# How to solve angle from area of circular segment formula?

Tags: numerical-methods, circles, angle

I know the radius $R$ of the circle and the area $A$ of the segment.

How can I solve for central angle $\alpha^{\circ}$ in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment#Area) (or some other) equation:

$$A=\frac{R^{2}}{2} \left( \frac{\alpha \pi}{180}-\sin \alpha^{\circ} \right)$$

?

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20171110160255/http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/faq.circle.segment.html) Newton's algorithm is recommended, but with an initial guess of

$$x(0) = (6k)^{1/3}$$

Why is this the initial guess?

Comment: you after numerical methods I suppose ...

Comment: @Math-fun Why??

Comment: your equation is a mixture of a polynomial and trigonometric function this does not in general admit a closed form solution and one has to rely on numerical methods.

Comment: I'm looking for if there's some other equation I could use, given this info that I have. Or a pointer into what kind of numerical method to use for the solution?

Comment: You would get $\alpha -\sin \alpha$= something, use the Taylor approx. for $\sin \alpha$.

Comment: rearrange your equation so that you have $g(\alpha)=0$ and take a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm

Comment: When $\alpha$ is small, $A\approx R^2\alpha^3/12$ (in radians).

Comment: Also, when using numerical methods, how can I select a proper initial guess? I can find many roots for this.

Comment: @Mew I get an equation of the form $\frac{\alpha^3R^2}{2}\left( -\frac{1}{120} \alpha^2-\frac{1}{\alpha^2}+\frac{\pi}{180\alpha^2}+\frac{1}{6} \right) - A = 0$. I don't understand why I'm allowed to solve the quadratic here?

Comment: @Mew Then it's $\frac{R^2\alpha}{2} \left( \frac{1}{6}\alpha^2+\frac{\pi}{180}-1\right)-A=0$. I don't seen how this is more revealing. I cannot conclude from the quadratic, because it's not a proper factor there.

Answer (score 2):

Your equation is transcendental,closed form solution is not possible. Newton -Raphson numerical iteration method is often used. If an approximate solution is acceptable, a graphical solution is also one method.

EDIT1:

By series expansion upto 2 terms we get a good approximation

$$ 2 A /R^2  = k \approx  \alpha - \sin \alpha  = \alpha ^3 /6$$

so we can choose a reasonably accurate value for starting iteration as:

$$ \alpha_{initial}= (6 k)^ { \frac13} .$$

Comment: I really wonder why you received a downvote for a good answer !

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I initially downvoted the answer before the edit, as I felt the first paragraph, while true, is somewhat redundant to what the OP said or didnt answer what the OP was asking for...  The OP didn't want a graphical solution and already knew that Newtons method is used.  However, the edit is fantastic, and i have thus removed my down vote and in fact up voted it :)

Comment: Thanks, gentlemen, there was  backlash from my side also.. it  took time to realize what OP was looking for.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen. It is very elegant to explain ! Thanks for acting this way.